# What is the probability of drawing at least one green and one blue marble in five draws with replacement in a bag with 100 marbles?

Tags: probability

The bag contains 100 marbles: 98 marbles are red, 1 marble is green, and 1 marble is blue. If you draw a marble five times, replacing it each time, what are the chances that those five draws contained at least one blue marble and one green marble?

I've tried solving this problem in so many ways; I'm fairly certain it boils down to:

$1-(P(Only\,Reds) + P(No\,Blue) + P(No\,Green))$

However, no matter how I've tried to calculate the probability, it doesn't match up with the probability I got from a Python simulation I performed.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried solving this problem in so many ways; I'm fairly certain it boils down to:
>
> 1−(P(Only Reds)+P(No Blue)+P(No Green))

It is: $\begin{align}\mathsf P({\small\textit{Blue}\geq 1\cap\textit{Green}\geq 1})&=(1-\mathsf P(\textit{No Blue}))+(1-\mathsf P(\textit{No Green}))-(1-\mathsf P(\textit{Only Red}))\\&=1-\mathsf P(\textit{No Blue})-\mathsf P(\textit{No Green})+\mathsf P(\textit{Only Red})\end{align}$

Since "Only Red" is "No Blue *and* No Green".

---

Recall: $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cup B)$

So too: $\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}\cap B^{\small\complement})=\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement})+\mathsf P(B^{\small\complement})-\mathsf P((A\cap B)^{\small\complement})$

Answer (score 0):

Your base assumptions are wrong. It says take the probability of at least one green and one blue so if you are picking a marble five times with replacement and you are looking for all the possibilities where you pick at least one blue marble and one green marble you will pick 1-4 green marble and 1-4 blue marbles and whose total number of green and blue  marbles are less than or equal to five. So the combination we need to exclude are below.

RRRRR, RRRRB, RRRBB, RRBBB, RBBBB, BBBBB, RRRRG, RRRGG, RRGGG, RGGGG, GGGGG

These are all the combinations that don't have at least one green and one blue since they are the possibilities that contain either a single color or they contain a combination of red and one other color. Since we don't care about the order, find the probability for each of these add them together and subtract the total from one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your expression. The correct one is:
$$
1 - P(\text{No Blue}) - P(\text{No Green})\color{red}+P(\text{Only Reds})=1-2\cdot0.99^5+0.98^5\approx 0.00194,
$$
where the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) was used.